# Dual-booted but cannot access Ubuntu after boot-repair

Tags: 13.04, dual-boot, boot-repair

My main OS is windows 7. Today I installed Ubuntu 13.04 alongside Windows. After successful installation everything seemed right. I could install programs and change system settings etc. However, when I rebooted my computer I had the error: No such device (Grub rescue). 
I've looked for solutions on several websites.

I tried using a boot-repair disk but now I cannot access Ubuntu any more. It's like my laptop is not dual-booted any more as I do not have the option to choose the OS on start-up.

Boot info script: http://paste.ubuntu.com/5974211/

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

Answer (score 1):

You have to change BIOS to boot external drive first, then internal drive. Then if external drive is not plugged in, it will boot the internal drive and just boot Windows, if plugged in it boots grub/Ubuntu.

You have Windows boot loader in sda, and grub2 in sdb, so Windows boots directly from internal drive and Ubuntu boots from external when plugged in, and will give the option to boot either Windows or Ubuntu.

Comment: I have tried that: I booted from my external drive (where the bootloader was stored). Then opened my terminal and used the following command: sudo grub-install /dev/sda.
It said installation was succesfull. So I rebooted and changed BIOS settings to boot from internal drive now. But I encountered the error grub rescue, no such device again. So I tried using the boot repair again, which gives the following boot-info:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/5974411/.
Now I have the same problem as I started from: can't access Ubuntu. Directly boots Windows

Comment: You do not want grub in sda, but Windows so when external drive is not connected you can boot internal drive. With grub on external drive then you only need to boot Ubuntu when external is connected.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your bootloader is stored on your second hard disk while its looking for it in the first hard disk.

so from your live-cd run boot-repair and install bootloader to /dev/sda

Answer (score 0):

Have you install  Ubuntu after Windows? you should install ubuntu after windows 
because its bootloader is very particular and the installer tends to overwrite the entire hard drive, wiping out any data stored on it.

Comment: I have installed ubuntu after Windows. I chose the option install Ubuntu alongside windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

after using

sudo grub-install /dev/sda

please also use

sudo update-grub

This would update the grub configuration.

Then set 1st hard disk as default in the bios menu, plug in the second hard disk, and reboot.

Tell us how it goes..

Answer (score -1):

you can use **sudo update-grub** command in ubuntu
actually if there is more than one os installed in your system then this command will update your grub(GNU GRand Unified Bootloader)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Can you please expand your answer to include an explanation of what this command does?